# \makecell option in currvita leaves a blank line in the second column

Tags: makecell, currvita

I am using `currvita` package to make my resume. I want to add a line on the left column and I used `\makecell`. However, using this package leaves a blank line in the right column. The result looks like this:

[image]
This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%Margins

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    right=20mm,
    bottom=15mm 
}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

%Font
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %\sfdefault
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{currvita,makecell}
\newcommand*{\ac}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\tolerance=600
\begin{document}
    \begin{cv}{My CV}

\begin{cvlist}{Berufserfahrung und Praxisphasen}

    \item[Year--Year ] Company, Town, Country\\
    Thesis\\
    Title
\end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: I want the Position and the word Thesis to be in one line

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It's generally easier for us to help if we can understand how the output you've posted is generated and nothing is better than code starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have posted my code. However, I have not included the word Position in the code that I have posted. I want to get the word Position and the word Thesis in the next column on the same line. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `\smash` with `\makecell[tl]` can do the trick:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    right=20mm,
    bottom=15mm 
}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

%Font
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %\sfdefault
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{currvita,makecell}
\newcommand*{\ac}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\tolerance=600
\begin{document}
    \begin{cv}{My CV}
        \begin{cvlist}{Berufserfahrung und Praxisphasen}
            \item[\smash{\makecell[tl]{Year--Year\\ Position}}] Company, Town, Country\\
            Thesis\\
            Title
        \end{cvlist}
    \end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok I have done so :)